# Setting an attribute value with __set() in OO PHP

Tags: php, oop, set

I am creating web pages via OO PHP. I have 4 public attributes at the top of my class:

```
class page {
    public $content;
    public $title = 'Default Title';
    public $buttons = array("Home"=>'index.php',
                            "Contact"=>'contact.php',
                            "Service"=>'service.php',
                            "About Us"=>'aboutus.php');
    public $keywords = 'These,are,the,keywords';

    // The __set() function should change the value of attributes.
    public function __set($name,$value){
        $this->name=$value;
    }
```

I have a method called Display() which displays all of my content to the user:

```
public function Display(){
    echo "<html>\n<head>\n";
    $this->DisplayTitle();
    $this->DisplayKeywords();
    $this->DisplayStyle();
    echo "</head>\n<body>\n";
    $this->DisplayHeader();
    $this->DisplayMenu($this->buttons);
    echo $this->content;
    $this->DisplayFooter();
    echo "</body>\n</html>\n";
}
```

Now What i am having trouble with is when I want to change the default value of title attribute from 'Default Title' to say 'Home Page' using __set() constructor nothing happens at all.

```
    $homepage->__set('title','Home Page');
```

I created a handler called `$homepage` on a seperate php file.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: [You're using `__set` incorrectly](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set).  You should just be doing `$homepage->title = 'Home Page'`

Comment: `__set` is a magic method you can't trigger it like a method. This is called everytime trying to access inaccessible properties. You need to manually create your setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong in the way that you are invoking the function, and you are also wrong where you define the function.

`__set`, as documented [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php), is a magic function. Therefor, you don't need to call it in the manner that you do. However, if you wanted to call it that way, I would suggest you rename it to `set` in order to not run into issues.

Calling the function would be as simple as this:

```
$homepage->title = 'Home Page';
```

This is because `__set` is called when a variable of a class is set. You also have an issue when you declare the function:

```
public function __set($name,$value){
    $this->name=$value;
}
```

That would always set the variable `name` to your value. You need to change it to this:

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->$name = $value;
}
```

That should work as expected.

Comment: Make sure you define you variables in your function! You are going to run into some serious bugs if you start adding variables whenever you want to

Comment: Thank you for your help. I knew i could change it like `$homepage->title = "Home Page"` but i read that accessing attributes outside of the class wasn't a good idea and that's why i used __set()

Answer (score 0):

In your `__set()` method change

```
$this->name=$value;
```

to

```
$this->$name=$value;
```